# Comenzar animaciones CSS después de la carga del DOM o window

Tags: javascript, html, css3

esta es mi primera pregunta.
Quería saber como hacer para que las animaciones CSS comiencen después de la carga de el DOM e imagenes, o por lo menos algunas imágenes.
Es para que las animaciones CSS no empiecen antes de la carga de las imágenes.
Conocen libraries o métodos estandar de hacerlo?
No he encontrado mucho al respecto. Si hay mucho sobre pre-loaders y animación css3 en general.
Lo poco que encontré es con window.addEventListener(load, callback(){});
Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score -2):

Con jQuery podés reconocer que una imagen cargó con el evento `load` y luego, una vez que termine de cargar la imagen agrego un clase al body para reconocer que ya se cargó y en los estilos css le condiciono esa clase para que haga la animación.

```js
$("img").one("load", function() {
  // agrego una clase al body
  $('body').addClass('images-load');
}).each(function() {
  // si termino de cargar la imagen
  if (this.complete) {
    $(this).load();
  }
});
```

```css
body span {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.images-load span {
  opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <span>Texto con animación</span>

  <img src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1" />

  <img src="http://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/small-memory-lp.jpg" />
</body>
```